# Pyside2 How To Get the window pops up to the front

Tags: qt, pyside2

**Scenario**
It's a pyside2 program running in Liunx system. There is a menu that every item in it is a exec. Every time I clicked the item, the exec starts if it's not started. The exec will pops up to the front if the exec is started. all the execs are External programs that I can't let them show just by change the code.

**approaches**
I use the xprop command to get the QT window handle, then use the QWindow apis to let the window show. just like this:

```
window = QWindow.fromWindId(handle)
window.setFlags(window.flags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show()
```

It works but has the problem that it always stays on top.
I change the code like this:

```
window = QWindow.fromWindId(handle)
window.setFlags(window.flags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show()
window.setFlags(window.flags() & ~Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show()
```

It does'not work, How can I just let the window to pop up to the front, not always on the top?
By the way, the *requestActivate()* and *raise()* not works either.

Comment: What happens if you don't set `WindowStaysOnTopHint` at all? Note that the docs explain that foreign native windows should not be manipulated through the QWindow interface (see the [`fromWinId()` note](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId)). You may have some success by using [`QWidget.createWindowContainer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer), but then you may have further issues related to focus and user input. In general, while it's theoretically supported, embedding foreign windows is discouraged as it's almost always unreliable.

Comment: The question is quite unclear, but it seems you are asking how to activate an external program that you've ***already started***. Qt cannot function as a window-manager, so you must use a third-party utility to do this. On Linux, a good choice is [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool#readme). If you use [QProcess.startDetached](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) to start the program, it will return the PID, which can be used to get the WID, like this: `xdotool search --pid PID`. Then you can bring the window to the front like this: `xdotool windowactivate WID`.